# mongodb spark connector, cannot write Dense or Sparse Vector

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mongodb-scala

I try to writing my dataframe with a column typed as "dense vector" in mongodb with mongo spark connector.

but i getting this error :

> cannot cast [2.0,2.0,115.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0] into a BsonValue.
>   org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT@3bfc3ba7 has no matching
>   BsonValue.

But why it is not cast as Array[Double], refer to :https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/

my dataframe schema :

```
root

|-- label: double (nullable = false)

|-- date: timestamp (nullable = true)

|-- features: vector (nullable = true)
```

Comment: The Mongo Spark connector doesn't know what to do with the vector type.  Its an internal `UserDefinedType` from the mllib library which the connector doesn't have a dependency on. You will have to convert it into an `Array[Double]` manually for it to save.

Comment: thanks ross :), maybe this can become a new feature ?

Comment: It would mean we'd have to take a dependency on the mllib library - so I'd prefer not to until its clear what they decide to do with UDT's.  I would like to use them for the unsupported bson types but currently they are private to spark.